# On a fixed beam, which force induces a counterclockwise torque

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque

Given this situation ($P$ is the point where the beam is fixed), which force induces a torque that is counterclockwise?

[image]

I want to use that : $ \boldsymbol{\tau} = \textbf{r} \times \textbf{F}$ , however what does counter clockwise torque mean? Intuitionally it would seem that $F_2$ would turn the beam around its own axis (counter clockwise) but so would $F_3$ and $F_5$.

So my question actually is: **what does counter clockwise torque mean in the context of this exercise?**

Any hints are  greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counter-clockwise means anti clockwise direction.

So this question is asking which force will rotate the rod in anti clockwise direction.
[image]

Comment: Yes, i know the meaning of the word. But in 3 dimensions there are 3 possible ways to go counter clockwise. What is meant in the context of this exercise? I dont have any experience with physics or engineering so i dont know for sure what is meant here.

Comment: Imagine the rod to be hour hand of the clock and now think which force(component) rotates the rod in anti clockwise direction.

Comment: And how exactly there are 3 possible ways?

Comment: xy plane, zx plane and yz plane, and in each you can go clockwise or counter clockwise ; so your comment doesnt really help

Comment: Is f2 perpendicular to the rod?

Comment: I think so, unfortunately this is the best representation of the exercise that i have. It seems to me that F2 and F4 are the only possibilities (F1 doesnt induce a torque) and 3 and 5 induce torques in a similar direction. But i really dont understand the question so...

Comment: I would say imagine clock in each plane then.

Comment: Appreciate your effort to help but im more confused from your drawing than i was before i started trying to solve this lol

Comment: @zokilokipoki what's the confusion?

Comment: I assume the torque is in purple and the forces are in red... Why is F2 showing downwards?

Comment: thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Clockwise is a vague term.You must be provided a reference frame or choose one so you can say your system moves clockwise or counter-clockwise in that frame. All the forces drawn except $F_1$ induce a torque